# An error has occured, I uninstalled firefox then this message kept showing everytime i start my laptop?

Tags: package-management, error-handling

[An error (using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) ("The cache has no package named'firefox:amd64'")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfsfN.png)

Comment: We don't know what OS/release you're using, so we're somewhat limited. Packages are built for releases, and `firefox` is **one of the package depends** that is required for some packages; so have you installed one of the *depends* rule **alternatives**? (ie. *you can meet the rule with other browsers, but not just any browser*) We don't even know your OS/release so can't help much currently.

Comment: using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS